# After logged and rerender view not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Below is my sidebar (menu) controller. This worked if a token existed in localstorage and I clicked logout.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal,$window, $timeout,$ionicHistory,$state,$rootScope) {
  var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  if(token){
    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
  }else{
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
  }

  $scope.logout = function(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
        $state.go('app.shop');
    })
  }

})
```

The view did get updated, I uses `loggedIn` for my `ng-show` in view.

My problem is in my login controller, the sidebar doesn't get refreshed after the login.

```
.controller('signupLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $location, $ionicHistory, $state) {
$scope.doLogin = function(email, password) {
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'myurl.com/login',
skipAuthorization: true,
headers: {
'owner': $rootScope.secret
},
data: {
email: email,
password: password
}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
if (response.data.success == true) {

        var tokenPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(response.data.msg);
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(tokenPayload));

        $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
          $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
          $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: true,
            historyRoot: true
          });
          $state.go('app.profile');
          $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        })

      } else {
        alert(response.data.msg);
      }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      alert(response.data)
    });
  }
```

The sidemenu view isn't get updated, any clue? I even tried hard refresh like `$state.go('app.profile',{},{reload:true})` and `window.location = '#/app/profile'`

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plunk with ui-router config??

Comment: @ZahidRahman I don't use ui-router, I'm using ionic framework.

Comment: @CodyJonas ionic internally uses ui-router. Could you show your router config?

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj what config? just this? `      .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'signupLoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })`